# jQuery Multiple Ifs

Tags: jquery, css

I want to be able to have something check if a CSS class exists somewhere and do something, then be able to check if another CSS class exists somewhere and do something. So if `.bp2` exists, do this, but also check if `.bp3` exists and if it does, do this other thing. They don't need to both exist and if the first exists, the second should still check itself and run too. Do I need to just copy/paste this code each time or is there a way to condense it all together?

```
$('.lot2').click(function () {
    if ($('.bp2').hasClass('showbp')) {
        $('.bp2').removeClass('showbp');
    } else {
        $('.bp2').addClass('showbp');
    }
});
```

Comment: You can use `.toggleClass()` instead of this `if`.

Comment: `$(".bp2").toggleClass("showbp");`

Comment: What is the other thing you want to do with `.bp3`? If it's the same, you can do `$(".bp2, .bp3").toggleClass("showbp")`

Answer (score 1):

You can perform multiple `if` statements.

```
$('.lot2').click(function() {
  if($(".bp2").length) {
    $(".bp2").each(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("showbp");
    });
  }
  if($('.bp3').length){
    // Do a thing
  }
});
```

Using the `.length` will help us determine if any elements of that selector exist. It will result in `0` or a number greater than `0`. An `if` statement will evaluate a `0` as False and `1` or higher as True.

Using `.each()` we can iterate each item of that collection. We can then use `.toggleClass()` to add or remove a specific class.

See More:

- https://api.jquery.com/length/
- https://api.jquery.com/each/
- https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/